# Using WebSecurity with an existing Mysql database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am an ICT student and 2 years back I learned how to deal with asp.net and mvc3. I had to make an easy website with a mysql database.

Now I want to make my own website with asp.net and MVC5, still using mysql. Yet so much has changed! I am trying to figure out how to work with WebSecurity for user authentication and SimpleMembership for authorization.

Right now I have two databases. One with the generated websecurity tables and one with my own tables. I cannot find a tutorial on the internet on how to use this kind of combination.

My questions are these:

- Is it logical to use these two databases in combination?
- When Websecurity.Login is called, what exactly happens? I have a users table in my mysql database. Is there a way the system can check those records?
- I have a table named "Users". I want to use this table instead of the aspnet_users generated table.
- How to use the connectionstring that is generated in my webconfig file?

I am trying to be as concrete as possible. But it is hard to define what I really need to know as I cannot find a good tutorial about websecurity in combination with a mysql database on the internet.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I just set up a site with the methods you're talking about.

The first step is to have your own users table in your own database. Which you say you already have. Great! Step 1 done. Now, in the ASP.NET application (assuming you're using the default template that comes with the account controller already in there and etc).

The other step is in your web.config file, make sure there's a default connection. You'll want to use the connection that your users table exists in.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="CONNSTRINGHERE" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

^It should look like that. You can, of course, use other connections here (just add another connection string inside of the  section).

NOW, the final step is go into the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs file. I could never get that code to work for me, but I commented out everything inside of the constructor and used this instead:

```html
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
                    {
                        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("CONNSTRINGHERE", "Users", "User_ID", "Username", autoCreateTables: true);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Something is wrong", ex);
                }
            }
```

Where it says "Users", you need to put the name of your database table there. You say yours is also just called users, so no changes need to be made.

So the way this all works is, you have your default connection defined to your database in the webconfig. Simplemembership knows your table is called users. Make sure there's a column called "username", and you should be good to go. The next time you run the app, it will autocreate four tables in your database for you: webpages_Membership, webpages_OAuthMembership, webpages_Roles, webpages_UsersInRoles. You can look at those and see how they can be used, etc. I won't go into detail.

BUT, your website will now use the login info from your users table to authenticate. When you create new users, it will use a combination of all those tables to authenticate.

Hopefully this helps you a little. Your connstrings may be different as I used sqlserver and you're using mysql. You can google the proper connstring format for those.